# Kubernetes Ingress with two namespaces, rewrite /api/ to development/api/

Tags: http, nginx, kubernetes, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress

I have Kubernetes app with two namespaces: project-production and project-development.
It contains of React frontend, Express backend and two databases. This is one of my ingress files. The second one is almost the same.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: project-development
  labels:
    name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io.ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: "/development/api/?(.*)"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: express-clusterip
                port:
                  name: express-port
          - path: "/development/?(.*)"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: react-clusterip
                port:
                  name: react-port
```

I need my frontend to be visible on paths:

- production -> localhost/production(/)
- development -> localhost/development(/)

One of the problems (not primary one) is that paths without / don't work.
The second one is that my frontend on both paths above is visible, but my axios requests send from them have the same path: http://localhost/api/
I want to rewrite requests coming from react to express throught nginx:

- [namespace project-development] http://localhost/api/ -> http://localhost/development/api
- [namespace project-production]  http://localhost/api/ -> http://localhost/production/api

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong, you want `path: "/development/(api/.*)"` for the first one.

Comment: I guess the previous one was working fine (the one you sent seems not working).
When I post http://localhost/development/api/1 using terminal it gives the right response.
The thing is I want ingress to rewrite path that react send (http://localhost/api/1) to the one above.